# Problems syncing photos and strange effects of uploaded files from other devices

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, android, folder, photo

I have a Galaxy Spica (GT-i5700) Android v2.1, rooted with Leshak dev 7 #123. But never mind the root info, the problem would be the same unrooted.

The photos from this phone is stored in "sdcard/images", nevertheless the phone also creates a "sdcard/DCIM" but only stores some thumbnails there.

**Problem nr 1:** U1 only reads the DCIM-folder for automatic photo-upload. So photos stored in this phone is not uploaded.
If I move photos to "DCIM" folder, U1 recognises the photos and start uploading them.

*Possible solution:* Could there be an option in the settings, to set preferred photo folder?

**Problem nr 2:** Out of 74 pictures, 12 did not get uploaded. Pressing "Retry failed transfers" in Settings does nothing. Pressing the files where status is "Upload failed, tap to retry" only changes the status to "Uploading..." but nothing gets uploaded.
If I upload another file to U1, it is uploaded directly without any problem.
It has nothing to do with file size, 1,1 MB files has been uploaded fine whilst some failed are 0,8 MB.

**Problem nr 3:** The photos from DCIM are in my case uploaded to a folder called "Pictures - GT-I5700" in U1. If I log in to the homepage and from there upload another photo in "Pictures - GT-I5700", it shows up in U1 on my phone fine. But when I tap it, U1 downloads the photo to "sdcard/U1/Pictures - GT-I5700". If it sync photos from "sdcard/DCIM" to a specific folder, why not also download files to the same folder from which it is synced?
After a while of usage, syncing and uploading files from different clients it would be a mishmash of folders and places files are stored and considering that I see no use of U1 at all.

**Another question:** If my SD card in some way breaks down/some folders cannot be read/card temporarly changed and U1 is running, does U1 consider that as files deleted and also delete from the cloud?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you have?

Comment: what **is** your problem? a single problem could have other reasons but still one question per question, not 4.

Answer (score 3):

Ad.1 We started with the substandard location of pictures, which is /mnt/sdcard (or whatever Android returns with getExternalStorageDirectory() method)  + /DCIM, so:
/mnt/sdcard/DCIM

Recently there have appeared vendors that provide custom mount points, such as /mnt/sdcard/ext or /mnt/sdcard/external_sd which have nothing to do with sdcard itself. We are aware of that (that's why we have allowed to cache music from Ubuntu One Music in such alternative location) and we will add support for custom photo directory. Possibly, for multiple custom directories.

Ad.2 You may want to enable U1F > Menu > Settings > Report problem > Collect logs, tap that problematic file, go back to the Report problem screen and send your logs. It'll help us understand what is the reason for that particular behaviour/bug.

Ad.3 If you upload a file from your device, and open it from Ubuntu One Files, it will open the picture from your device, instead of downloading it from the cloud (since it has been uploaded from that device, right?). If you delete the picture from your gallery/sdcard/however you want, if you try to open that picture from U1F, it'll then download the file. You are right - the location of all files downloaded with U1F is set to /mnt/sdcard/u1, and it was not an easy decision to make. We did not want to clutter user's storage, but at the same time we wanted to provide an easily accessible location. As far as downloading pictures to that location instead of /mnt/sdcard/DCIM - Ubuntu One Files, apart from auto-upload of photos, does not provide sync capabilities. We want to be very clear about that. Thus, we do not operate on the locations of files you upload, we stick to one location (/mnt/sdcard/u1) to manage your files from U1 cloud. However -- once we provide sync capabilities, we will make new decisions on how to approach these type of matters. Most probably, you'll be able to map custom device location to custom cloud location. Currently, this is not supported.

Ad.4 No, because Ubuntu One Files does not (yet) do sync. And if it did, I guarantee we will do our best to detect such edge cases, as well as disable populating file deletions to the cloud as an application setting for your convenience.

I hope this answers your questions. Do let us know about Ad.2 (you can send the logs like I have described above). Cheers!